# Problem with quotes

Tags: posts

I have a strange problem with the latest version of Wordpress: Some writers, when they write a story, you see the quote character `'`, replaced with `/`, something that does not happen to me. Is there any special settings in the CMS that could cause this annoying problem?

Comment: If you write a double quote ( \" ) , have you the same problem?

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to TwentyEleven. Does it still happen?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this are regional settings involved here. I don't think that issue is showing somewhere else. Maybe they are copying their text from somewhere else.

Comment: The strange thing is that until a few weeks ago did not have these problems...

Comment: @Daniele Oreste Marino What exactly changed in those few weeks and from which versions to which new versions?

Comment: The version actually installer are 3.5!